# How to implement "loading views" for async operations on Android in generic way?

Tags: android, user-interface, design-patterns, asynchronous, event-bus

Every application, which performs some background work on user requests, has to somehow indicate that is busy - usually showing some animated "loading view".

How this behavior can be implemented in generic way? 
By "generic" I mean:

1. No copy-pasting xml/java code for each screen of the application (some base activity/fragment class with dynamic layout modification?)
2. No code for showing/hiding "loading view" in concrete activity/fragment classes (publishing events when starting/finishing async operation?)

In other words, implementing some concrete screen, I don't have to think about loading views.

Has someone implemented something like this?

Edit: more specific example

Let's say I have screens A, B and C, implemented as Fragments in one Activity. Each screen has to async load some data before it's standard view can be displayed, do we have to show spinner until the data is fetched.

I'd like to implement this functionality in some BaseFragment, so in FragmentA, FragmentB, FragmentC, I don't have to think about it - I just call async operation and loading will show automatically. The respective layouts a.xml, b.xml, c.xml, also should not contain any additional views.

Comment: Are you using AsyncTask class?

Comment: I'm looking for the best solution to this problem, so any framework would be ok.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you mean by the two generic conditions. But the usual way is not to keep loading views, it's to define a progress bar in the xml file (or if you want, dynamically and add it to the view by code), then update the bar based on some task. If this is what you're looking for, let me know so I can post an answer based on the usage of asyncTask, otherwise, clarify the two conditions.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the question.

Comment: What about defining a single general fragment for loading which will be called whenever you do a task in the background and replaced once the task is over?

Comment: Nice option, in addition to containing a spinner, it could encapsulate all loading behavior (e.g. adding specific handling for back pressed).

Comment: But what if I had two-fragment layout for tablets? How do I know for which part should I show it?

Comment: Yes you can encapsulate all loading related components in one fragment and handle different events. Regarding the tablet layout, as I remember every fragment can be given a tag or ID. Say the id of one of the fragments is firstFragment, then when a component inside it is clicked to fire the loading process replace firstFragment with the loading fragment. BTW, I think by spinner you mean a busy cursor or something to indicate time dependent processes, but in Android it refers to a component that works as a drop down list. If this is what you want let me know so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Sure, post your solution as an answer, it would be better for discussion.
I know that this is the name of the component, but I noticed that it is also used as the name of progress bar (which usually is not a bar :) ), e.g.: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_loading_spinner.htm

Comment: Ok, now I see what you meant by spinner :), I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may define a single general fragment for loading which will be called whenever you do a task in the background and replaced once the task is over.

If you're designing a layout for a tablet which some times include two fragments within the same activity you can know which one to replace using its tag or ID. Say the id of one of the fragments is firstFragment, then when a component inside it is clicked to fire the loading process, you can replace firstFragment with the loading fragment.

If you'll be using AsyncTask class for executing the task, you can update the progress bar inside onProgressUpdate method.

Here are some useful links:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress%28int%29

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I know Android "standard library" pretty well, I just wonder how to put those building blocks together to create some framework.

Comment: Regarding your solution, I'm affraid it does not work that way - id in FragmentTransaction.replace() is id of the container view in activity's content layout xml. So, something inside that fragment would have to know in which container it is placed, what I think is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I post my solution, which I have developed so far. However, I hope there is some easier/smarter approach.

I have abstract BaseFragment class, which wraps (in onCreatView()) the view created by concrete fragment with manually inflated layout:

```
<FrameLayout>
  <LoadingView/>
  <ConcreteFragmentView/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Each async operation is executed on CommandExecutor class:

```
public class CommandExecutor{

  void execute(Runnable callback){
    //  1. post event "loading started"
    //  2. execute callback on background thread
    //  3. post event "loading completed"
    //  4. post results
  }
}
```

Events are posted using event bus (I'm using Greenrobot's one).

Base fragment listens for loading started/completed events and shows/hides loading view.

Pros:

- subclasses of BaseFragment doesn't have to know anything about progress indicators
- progress indicators are in scope of single fragment, so there is no problem with multi-fragment screens

Cons:

- it doesn't look good when loading ends during animation
- deeper hierarchy, manual layout inflation
- forced inheritance